# Facebook Graph API - Tag Photo

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to tag a photo using `/{photo-id}/tags`. These are the parameters I am sending:

```
{
    tags = "[{'tag_uid': 'FRIENDS_ID', 'x':1, 'y':1}]";
}
```

This works fine if i use my App-Scoped ID, but it doesn't work with my regular ID.

This is the error that i am receiving ("(#100) The global X id is not allowed for this call"):
[image]

So, it does work with my App-Scoped ID, retrieved using `/me`, but it doesn't work with any other regular ID, neither mine or of my friends.

Do any of you have ideas of what's causing this?

Comment: Well, the answer is already in your question. You cannot use the "global" ID in apps anymore.

Comment: @luschn. Hmm, what should i use then ?

Comment: the app scoped IDs? ;)

Comment: how do you even get those IDs? you would get app scoped ids anyway if you make calls to /me/friends, for example. not sure why you would even want to use global IDs.

Comment: I am getting them from user's address book. They match the ones i get from findmyfacebookid.com, so i think you're right, they're app-scoped ids, but i still don't understand why i doesn't work.

Comment: ...because only app scoped ids are allowed nowadays. not sure what´s NOT to understand, to be honest. it´s a feature, not a bug ;)

Comment: meaning: apps should ALWAYS use app scope ids, and app scoped ids is what you get in apps. you are not supposed to use any IDs from elsewhere.

Comment: if they match IDs from any other app, then they are not app scoped. that is what app scoped means: only available in your app.

Comment: @luschn, thanks. i think i understand now. What endpoint of the API should i use in order to get the app-scoped id of an user from it's username ?

Comment: where did you get the username? you dont get the username anymore either. anyway, i will create an answer about what you should use for tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already commented, you can only use App Scoped IDs in Apps, and those are only unique in your own App. You can only match them with another App you own, by using the [Business Mapping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business).

For tagging, you should use `taggable_friends`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/taggable_friends

Comment: That's what i've been looking for, but is there a way to filter those, or do i have to retrieve all the friends in order to use just a few? Also, when i call this, it only returns just a 1000 of friends. Is there a way to adjust this?

Comment: "just" 1000? who got THAT many friends? lol...anyway, there may be a paging object for getting the next batch.

Comment: ...but i think the list is ranked by users who are most likely to get tagged by the authorized user.